# While loop in compute shader is crashing my video card driver

Tags: c++, direct3d, hlsl, compute-shader

I am trying to implement a Binary Search in a compute shader with HLSL. It's not a classic Binary Search as the search key as well as the array values are `float`. If there is no matching array value to the search key, the search is supposed to return the last index (`minIdx` and `maxIdx` match at this point). This is the worst case for classic Binary Search as it takes the maximum number of operations, I am aware of this.

So here's my problem:

My implementation looks like this:

```
uint BinarySearch (Texture2D<float> InputTexture, float key, uint minIdx, uint maxIdx)
{
    uint midIdx = 0;
    while (minIdx <= maxIdx)
    {
        midIdx = minIdx + ((maxIdx + 1 - minIdx) / 2);
        if (InputTexture[uint2(midIdx, 0)] == key)
        {
            // this might be a very rare case
            return midIdx;
        }

        // determine which subarray to search next
        else if (InputTexture[uint2(midIdx, 0)] < key)
        {
            // as we have a decreasingly sorted array, we need to change the
            // max index here instead of the min
            maxIdx = midIdx - 1;
        }

        else if (InputTexture[uint2(midIdx, 0)] > key)
        {
            minIdx = midIdx;
        }
    }

    return minIdx;
}
```

This leads to my video driver crashing on program execution. I don't get a compile error.

However, if I use an `if` instead of the `while` I can execute it and the first iteration works as expected.

I already did a couple of searches and I suspect this might have to do something with dynamic looping in a compute shader. But I have no prior experience with compute shaders and only little experience with HLSL as well, which is why I feel kind of lost.

I am compiling this with `cs_5_0`.

Could anyone please explain what I am doing wrong or at least hint me to some documentation/explanation? Anything that can get me started on solving and understanding this would be super-appreciated!

Comment: AFAIK there's a limit on the number of loops you can do, usually in the order of 256 or so..

Comment: your `minIdx = midIdx` in the final elseif should probably be `minIdx = midIdx + 1`. since you don't increase the lower bound, you can get into an infinite loop.

Comment: This code can get stuck in a loop in C++, so I doubt that HLSL has anything to do with it. (Search for 2.1 in `{3.0, 2.0, 1.0}` and you'll get stuck.)

Comment: You are right. I feel dumb now. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

DirectCompute shaders are still subject to the Timeout Detection & Recovery (TDR) behavior in the drivers. This basically means if your shader takes more than 2 seconds, the driver assumes the GPU has hung and resets it. This can be challenging with DirectCompute where you intentionally want the shader to run a long while (much longer than rendering usually would). In this case it may be a bug, but it's something to be aware of.

With Windows 8.0 or later, you can allow long-running shaders by using `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DISABLE_GPU_TIMEOUT` when you create the device. This will, however, apply to all shaders not just DirectCompute so you should be careful about using this generally.

For special-purpose systems, you can also use [registry keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569918.aspx) to disable TDRs.